# Reference Request: Analysis of "If you have questions, I'll be available after class"

Tags: discussion

I am looking for resources analyzing the phrase "if you have questions, I'll be available after class." Although this is structured like a conditional, and will sometimes be said with a "then" after the comma, it's not actually a semantically reasonable conditional statement. Instead of using the first clause to limit the scope of the truth of the second clause, the speaker is using the first clause to address the second clause to a subset of the audience. I've come across people using phrases structured like this frequently in casual conversation in the United States.

Comment: @NVZ I specifically asked if this would be on-topic first on this meta and was told to post it on meta instead of on the main site.

Comment: Natural language isn't like computer language. The 'if then' syllogistic syntax is only one meaning of 'if'. I wouldn't be surprised if the OED had an entry on 'if' that showed something like your example. (you can usually get online use of OED through a public or university library)

Comment: @NVZ Yeah dude, kind of contradictory.

Comment: @StellaBiderman Okay, I see it now. I wonder if it's really answerable here though.

Comment: @Mitch I missed the part where it says "resource request". Oops.

Comment: StellaBiderman Maybe what @NVZ is saying is that you might better ask this question on main without the request for reference. That is, ask about the phenomenon here. ELU is not primarily a jump off place for other services, but is intended to answer questions here.

Comment: @Mitch Exactly, that. You read my mind as well.

Comment: This construction is called a _false conditional_ or an _indirect conditional_. The CGEL (p740) calls the protasis of such constructions a _relevance protasis_, whereby the main clause is independently true of the condition. Elsewhere on this site @Ilmari Karonen has a good answer to question about the construction _I made sandwiches, if you want some_: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/137581/how-does-the-false-conditional-work-in-i-made-sandwiches-if-you-want-some

Comment: There are answers on ELU to questions about this construction; you can find them by following the links in your ELU question or by using the search box.  And StoneyB gave you a book reference: "DeClerck and Reed, Conditionals: A Comprehensive Empirical Analysis, 2001, call this use of the construction "relevance conditionals"--the protasis defines the circumstances under which the apodosis is relevant to the hearer."  This is a full treatment--you can follow up from there.

Comment: Ask this question on EL&U, but in the form of "Is this really a conditional?" or something. If you ask for a well-referenced answer you'll get your sources. These types of conditional are known by many names: *biscuit conditionals* after Austin, *relevance conditionals* and many more.